# Query to return data for the past 6 months

Tags: ms-access

I'm having some troubles in trying to figure out a date criteria in a query. Basically, I'm trying to get all the data from the past 6 months. For example, the current month is December 2017; I would like the query to return data ranging from June to December 2017. I've tried the following criteria:

Between Date() and DateAdd ("M", -6, Date())

However, the criteria returns data based on the day of the date; if the current date is 2 December 2017, the query returns dates from 2 June to 2 December 2017. I want the query to return data from the whole month of June (therefore if we're following the previous example, data from 1 June 2017 will be included too) to December. How do I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having sounds quite simple. You really just need to use the 1st day of the current month, instead of the current date.

There are many ways to get the first day of the current month, for example:

```
Date() - Day(Date()) + 1
```

<sub>While there are alternate ways to do this, try not to rely on casting a date to a string and back for performance/locale incompatibility</sub>

If you use this approach, your SQL WHERE would be:

```
Between Date() - Day(Date()) + 1 and DateAdd ("M", -6, Date() - Day(Date()) + 1)
```